# I got a docker error on react+vite.js project

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, vite

```
 Database is available
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | failed to load config from /frontend/vite.config.js
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | error when starting dev server:
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | Error:
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | install a platform-specific binary executable.
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | Specifically the "@esbuild/win32-x64" package is present but this platform
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | needs the "@esbuild/linux-x64" package instead. People often get into this
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | situation by installing esbuild on Windows or macOS and copying "node_modules"
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | into a Docker image that runs Linux, or by copying "node_modules" between
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | Windows and WSL environments.
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | If you are installing with npm, you can try not copying the "node_modules"
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | directory when you copy the files over, and running "npm ci" or "npm install"
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | on the destination platform after the copy. Or you could consider using yarn
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | instead of npm which has built-in support for installing a package on multiple
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | platforms simultaneously.
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | If you are installing with yarn, you can try listing both this platform and the
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | other platform in your ".yarnrc.yml" file using the "supportedArchitectures"
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | feature: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#supportedArchitectures
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | Keep in mind that this means multiple copies of esbuild will be present.
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | Another alternative is to use the "esbuild-wasm" package instead, which works
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | the same way on all platforms. But it comes with a heavy performance cost and
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | can sometimes be 10x slower than the "esbuild" package, so you may also not
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  | want to do that.
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at generateBinPath (/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1888:17)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at esbuildCommandAndArgs (/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1969:33)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at ensureServiceIsRunning (/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2133:25)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at build (/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2025:26)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at bundleConfigFile (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:66194:26)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at loadConfigFromFile (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:66170:31)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at resolveConfig (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:65767:34)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at _createServer (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:65044:26)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at createServer (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:65041:12)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |     at CAC.<anonymous> (file:///frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:763:30)
ecommerce_project-frontend-1  |
ecommerce_project-frontend-1 exited with code 1


  **FROM node:21
    WORKDIR /frontend
    COPY package.json  ./
    RUN npm i
    RUN npm install react-redux
    RUN rm package-lock.json
    COPY package.json /frontend/package.json
    COPY package-lock.json /frontend/package-lock.json
    EXPOSE 5173
    CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]**
```

this is my docker file for react project,correct me if anything wrong here.
i got this error while i running the following command **"docker-compose up"**. how can i solve this error and what is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried this configs and fixed

vite.config.js

```js
export default defineConfig({
    esbuild: {
        target: 'esnext',
        platform: 'linux'
    },
    // other configs
}
```

and for yarn package manager

```json
"resolutions": {
    "esbuild": "npm:esbuild-wasm"
}
```